# How do I separate concerns with Object Oriented Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a javascript module that changes the height of a textarea as users type into it.

So far it's functional, but I'm not convinced that it's "correct" Object Oriented javascript. Specifically, I'm not sure that I have the right behaviour in each section of the code.

Is using `self` from `var self = this;` in the constructor the only way to access the instance, in, for example, the event listener? (I couldn't find a way to call `Multiline.textarea` without `self.textarea`)

Should I be putting  `this.textarea.css("overflow", "hidden");` in the middle of my constructor? For readability, should I be putting that in a method that is a part of the prototype?

```
// input resizing:

// give the item a class of .multiline
// for each .multiline, create a Multiline object that has, saved to it, the textarea it was created on.

$( document ).ready( function(){
  $(".multiline").each(function(){
    new Multiline(this);
  });
});


// constructor:
function Multiline(textarea){
  var self = this;
  this.textarea = $(textarea);

  // Give the textarea "overflow: hidden;" to hide scrollbars when newline formed
  this.textarea.css("overflow", "hidden");

  this.fakeTextField = this.createFakeField(this.textarea);
  this.textarea.on('change keydown keypress keyup', function(){
    self.setHeightOfTextarea(self)
  });
}

Multiline.prototype.createFakeField = function(textarea) {  
  // Equivelant to fake = textarea.clone();
  var fake =  $('<div></div>');

  // Add the relevant CSS from the textarea so fonts match
  var css_selectors = ["width", "padding", "line-height", "font-size", "letter-spacing", "word-wrap", "border"]
  $.each(css_selectors, function(index, value){
    fake.css(value, $(textarea).css(value))
  });

  // remove multiline class to prevent another "multiline" object being built
  fake.removeClass("multiline");

  // attach invisibibly to the DOM
  fake.css("display", 'none' );
  $("body").append(fake);

  // store as multiline's "fakeTextField"
  return fake
}

Multiline.prototype.setHeightOfTextarea = function(self) {
  // Put the text in the box.
  self.fakeTextField.html( self.textarea.val() );

  self.textarea.css("min-height", self.fakeTextField.outerHeight() + "px")
}
```

Comment: There's no need to pass a reference to the target object (like with `setHeightOfTextarea()`) when you call it as a method. When you call it like `self.setHeightOfTextarea()` the value of `this` inside of the function will be a reference to the same object, in other words.

Comment: `var self = this;` is a very common idiom in javascript. And yes, in the event listener, `this` won't be the object, so using a closure (like you are doing) is the way to do it.